# Python how to make specific output using if in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to write a `...for` loop that isolates the elements in a series that correspond with a change in the value:

```
Input example: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 2
```

```
Desired output: 1 2 3 1 2 <--- stores only the values that change from the previous value
```

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is to count vehicles in a video. The algorithm that I used in this code is background subtraction and connected component labelling. Cropping the video to specific size I'm trying to add code that counts "blobs" that pass through the frame.

The code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv


backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
backSub.setVarThreshold(150)
capture = cv.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

total_vehicle = 0 
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    crop = frame[300:, 260:360]
    if frame is None:
        break
    
    fgMask = backSub.apply(crop)
    


    #erode-dilate
    erode_img = cv.erode(fgMask, cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,3)),iterations=2)
    dilate_img = cv.dilate(erode_img,cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,3)),iterations=6)

    #contour
    con = cv.findContours(dilate_img, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

    color = cv.cvtColor(dilate_img, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    image = cv.drawContours(crop, con, -1, (0,255,0),2)

    output = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(dilate_img, 8, cv.CV_32S)
    (nolabel, label, stats, centroid) = output

    blob = 0
    for i in range(0, nolabel):
        if stats[i,cv.CC_STAT_AREA]>10:
            blob += 1
            #want to edit this statement
            if blob > 1:
                total_vehicle += 1
                
    print(total_vehicle)
    
    cv.imshow('Frame', frame)
    cv.imshow('dilate', dilate_img)



    
    keyboard = cv.waitKey(30)
    if keyboard == 'q' or keyboard == 27:
        break
```

`total_vehicle` is tracking the total number of blobs, but not filtering just those values that differ from the previous one.

Comment: You have to give it a shot first.  You just need to remember what the last number was, and print (and remember) if the number changes.

Comment: What is the input ? Share your actual code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you actually show to us. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. However, what you're asking makes very little sense and it sounds as if you don't know enough in order to *describe* the problem properly, never mind solve it. Stack Overflow cannot help you in this case. You should try following a tutorial, talking to your instructor, or as a last resort a discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: I can't understand how your variable can decrease ? your only increment total_vehicle

Comment: The decrease is in the blob. If the blob > 1 in the video, the total vehicle is incremented. But, if it stays in >1, like 2 2 2 2, the total vehicle keep incremented. I just want the total vehicle increment based on its change.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have a list with numbers:

```
numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

You can simply loop through the numbers and check their value with a pre-assigned note variable, which stores the last printed number.

```
note = None # Assign variable with no value
for number in numbers:
    if number != note:
        note = number
        print(number, end=" ")
```

The output of this would be:

```
>>> 1 2 3 1 2
```

**Note:** I've used `print(number, end=" ")` in order to print the output in one line, like in your given example.